# export_png is timing out

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to save a bokeh figure as a png file but whenever I use export_png it returns this error:

```
    File "/home/tuf60598/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
    File "/home/tuf60598/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
six.raise_from(e, None)
    File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
    File "/home/tuf60598/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    File "/home/tuf60598/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
response.begin()
    File "/home/tuf60598/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    File "/home/tuf60598/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

This is how I call it:

```
    p = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=1000, x_axis_label='time(in seconds)',y_axis_label='y', title="Accesses over time")`

    p.circle(x, y, size=4, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

    export_png(p, filename="access_over_time.png")
```

Why does this happen?

Note: This only happens when I try to plot a dataset that has millions of rows. Otherwise, when working with datasets that has ~30k rows, it doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Are you using Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: @Tony nope. I’m using the python REPL

Comment: Looks very similar like this issue https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1327 Did you post it? Otherwise it is worth to have a look on it.